Pass WP data to javascript
I'm using data attributes to pass product price calculation formula to javascript. Is it possible to pass it to javascript without being displayed in page source code?

client side javascript is executed by the browser then there no other way to retrieve data. edit your question to give us more details and we may help you to find another architecture for your application.

Hello @jaroMT - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! As mmm mentions, more information would be useful in order to provide a better answer more applicable to your situation. You might take a moment to read through the "[ask]" page in our [help], then file an [edit] to your question if you believe it could be improved.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The most direct answer to your question as it stands is "yes" - there are many ways to acquire data from WordPress without embedding it in the page's markup or an inline <script> generated via wp_add_inline_script()/wp_localize_script(). A couple of options would be to have your JavaScript make a web request to the REST API (either one of the preexisting endpoints, or a custom one), or a custom AJAX handler.
However, note that there is no way to completely conceal data delivered to the browser from savvy users. A browser's dev tools can be used to examine the value of any JavaScript variable, as well as inspect cookies and web requests - there's simply no way to completely hide usable data from visitors.
If you can provide more information about your application and needs, someone may be able to offer a better solution.
